# AngularJs make an element draggable or droppable dynamically in DOM

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I am looking for any directive or anything that works with angularJs to make an element draggable or droppable dynamically in DOM.

Like there is an element in DOM which is draggable, i want to make it droppable and disable its draggable properties.

I checked many directives. Can anyone suggest me something?

Answer (score 1):

The most polished directive I have found is : [Angular Gridster](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster)

Though I am not really sure what the use case is.  [Greensock's Draggable with Throw Props](https://www.greensock.com/draggable/) plugin is very nice and easily put into a directive...